# Python: Keep first occurrence of an item in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

How can I remove all occurrences of a specific value in a list except for the first occurrence?
E.g. I have a list:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c']
```

And I need a function that looks something like this:

```
preserve_first(letters, 'c')
```

And returns this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a']
```

Removing all but the first occurrence of the given value while otherwise preserving the order. If there is a way to do this with a `pandas.Series` that would be even better.

Comment: Why have you duplicated the 'a' values at the end?

Comment: In your final output the last two elements, `['a', 'a']`,  although seen first at the beginning of the list, are preserved. Why is that?

Comment: OP's function takes `'c'`.  OP expects this to preserve the first `'c'` and not consider any other values.

Comment: What @piRSquared said, I want to eliminate all occurrences except the first for a specific value. The rest of the duplicates can't be changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to remove duplicates of `'c'` only.  So you want to filter where the series is either not duplicated at all **or** it isn't equal to `'c'`.  I like to use `pd.Series.ne` in place of `pd.Series !=` because the reduction in wrapping parenthesis adds to readability (my opinion).

```
s = pd.Series(letters)

s[s.ne('c') | ~s.duplicated()]

0    a
1    b
2    c
5    d
7    a
8    a
dtype: object
```

---

To do exactly what was asked for.

```
def preserve_first(letters, letter):
    s = pd.Series(letters)
    return s[s.ne(letter) | ~s.duplicated()].tolist()

preserve_first(letters, 'c')

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a']
```

Comment: So simple... Well done.  Note a slight typo in your function, should be: `return s[s.ne(letter) | ~s.duplicated()].tolist()`

Comment: Brilliant. Can you add an explanation of what `s.ne` does?

Comment: @r3robertson I added some commentary.  I tend to use `ne` for `!=`, `lt` for `<`, `le` for `<=`, `gt` for `>`, `ge` for `>=`, and `eq` for `==`.  I think it simplifies the code.  This is a personal style preference of mine.

Comment: @piRSquared great logical thinking - awesome!

Comment: Thanks @JonClements

Answer (score 3):

A general Python solution:

```
def keep_first(iterable, value):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for val in it:
        yield val
        if val == value:
            yield from (el for el in it if el != value)
```

This yields all items up to and including the first value if found, then yields the rest of the iterable filtering out items matching the value.

Comment: @r3robertson been quite a while since I've been stuck having to use 2.7... but yeah, you'd need to change the `yield from` to an explicit `for` loop and `yield`...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using generators:

```
def conserve_first(l, s):
     last_seen = False
     for i in l:
         if i == s and not last_seen:
               last_seen = True
               yield i

         elif i != s:
               yield i

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c']
print(list(conserve_first(letters, "c")))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c']

def preserve_first(data, letter):
    new = []
    count = 0
    for i in data:
        if i not in new:
            if i == letter and count == 0:
                new.append(i)
                count+=1
            elif i == letter and count == 1:
                continue
            else:
                new.append(i)
        else:
            if i == letter and count == 1:
                continue
            else:
                new.append(i)  

l = preserve_first(letters, "c")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list filter and slices:

```
def preserve_first(letters, elem):
    if elem in letters:
        index = letters.index(elem)
        return letters[:index + 1] + filter(lambda a: a != 'c', letters[index + 1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't use pandas but this is a simple algorithm to do the job.

```
def preserve_firsts(letters, target):
    firsts = []
    seen = False
    for letter in letters:
        if letter == target:
            if not seen:
                firsts.append(letter)
                seen = True
        else:
            firsts.append(letter)
    return firsts

> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a']
> preserve_firsts(letters, 'c')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I could come up with.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c']
key = 'c'

def preserve_first(letters, key):
    first_occurrence = letters.index(key)
    return [item for i, item in enumerate(letters) if i == first_occurrence or item != key]
```